# Pythonの文字列から不要な記号を削除して、リストにしたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

```
["明日","昨日","晴れ"]
```

このような文字列 (リストではない)をリストに戻したいのですが、

```
re.sub('\[', "", 変数)
re.sub('\'', "", 変数)
```

などで、不要な文字列を消してから、split(',')をしてリストにしようと考えていたのですが、どうしても正規表現で削除することができません。

どのようにすれば、この文字列を

```
[明日,昨日,晴れ]
```

のようなリストに変更できるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `eval` する方法が考えられます。`eval('["明日","昨日","晴れ"]')`

Comment: metropolisさんありがとうございました。そちらで解決しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

文字列表現データ(リスト) からデータ構造を復元する場合
よく使われるのは JSONです。

(すでに evalで解決しているようですが, 手っ取り早く簡単でも危険性をはらんでいるので, 例えば外部サービスに利用するなどは止めたほうが良いでしょう)

```py
import json

data_string = '''
    ["明日","昨日","晴れ"]
    '''
val = json.loads(data_string)
```

Comment: 問題点についても解説いただきありがとうございました。